# PHP associative Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array in PHP

```
$asd['a'] = 10;
$asd['b'] = 1;
$asd['c'] = 6;
$asd['d'] = 3;
```

i want to sort this on basis of its value and to get the key value for the first 4 values.

how can i do that in php ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[asort()](http://php.net/asort) should keep the index association:

```
asort($asd);
```

After that, a simple foreach can get you the next four values

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($asd as $key=>$value)
{
  if ($i >= 4) break;
  // do something with $asd[$key] or $value
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: what if i want to sort in descending order?/

Comment: Oops, I forgot the $i++. Thanks Greg.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to the other answers. This one without a loop:

```
asort($asd);
$top_four_keys = array_slice(array_keys($asd), 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [asort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) function's what you need to sort it.

To get the values, you can use code like this:

```
$myKeys = array_keys(asort($asd));
$myNewItems = Array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    $myNewItems[$myKeys[$i]] = $asd[$myKeys[$i]];
```

Which will put the first fur items into `$myNewItems`, with the proper keys and sort order.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add...

```
asort($asd,SORT_NUMERIC);
$top_four_keys=array_slice(array_keys($asd), 0, 4);
```

For descending order:

```
arsort($fruits,_SORT_NUMERIC);
$top_four_keys=array_slice(array_keys($asd), 0, 4);
```

You may need to use `SORT_NUMERIC` parameter,
in case of you have an unexpected array.